# If article:published_time and article:modified_time have the same dates, should I use article:modified_time?

Tags: seo, technical-seo, open-graph-protocol, twitter-card

```html
<meta property="article:published_time" content="2022-11-17T17:16:45+00:00"/>
<meta property="article:modified_time" content="2022-11-17T17:16:45+00:00"/>
```

As you can see in the meta codes above, both of the texts in the content fields are the same.

In this case I should use `article:modified_time` meta tag?

Comment: Maybe hide modified time, until it is updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking if it will impact SEO, then showing both the same will likely not. Google has some logic implemented and picks whichever it decides is more relevant to display on it's SERP. Google has stated that dates are part of their algorithm, and I'm assuming that's still true, but John Mueller has indicated it isn't easily confused by them.

**Which date type does Google use: Last Modified or Published?**

> "That's something that we we sometimes argue with with the dates team. But I see they're good arguments both ways. And in our algorithms we don't always pick like one or the other as the one that would show.
> So sometimes we feel that the original date makes sense the show sometimes it makes sense to show the last modification date where we know that something significantly changed on this page that affects what the user is looking for.
> So I think there are arguments that could be made for both directions. And that's kind of why we try to be bit flexible there with the algorithms." - John Mueller